# How Can I send mailing with AWS SES API instead of SMTP?

Tags: api, mailing, civicrm-home

I want to send mailing with the help of AWS SES API instead of SMTP. I am using CiviCRM 5.32.2 and drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

This extension may be of interest, but it doesn't allow sending via API: https://github.com/mecachisenros/aws

I think you would need to write your own code to integrate with the SES API. But AWS works perfectly fine via SMTP.